# No type was found that matches the controller named 'help'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have been following [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/21/asp-net-web-api-generating-a-web-api-help-page-using-apiexplorer.aspx) to add a help page to document my Web API project. My Controller is named HelpController and I have a route that I am trying to use to map the Index action to /Help. This is the only MVC controller in the project. Because the rest are Web API controllers, we removed the "/api" prefix from the default route in WebAPIConfig.cs.

The HelpController:

```
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
        return View(apiExplorer);
    }
}
```

And route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "help",
            defaults: new { controller = "Help", action = "Index"});

    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  // ..
  WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  // ..
}
```

But when I try to navigate to /help in the browser I get the following error message.

```
<Error>
  <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/ws/help'.</Message>
  <MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'help'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

**EDIT**: The message contains /ws/help as the application is hosted at localhost/ws in IIS.

Does anyone know what could be causing ASP.NET to not find my HelpController?

**UPDATE**: If I change the order of RouteConfig and WebApiConfig registration calls in Application_Start I get a 404 instead.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  // ..
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
  // ..
}
```

Comment: That route would seem to work for `http://localhost/help` you seem to be going to `http://localhost/ws/help` is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes. This is hosted as an application called ws within a website in IIS.

Comment: The error message refers to `help` rather than `Help` (note the case) have you tested using `Help` as the url.

Comment: @TomStyles yes. Same response unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The request for `help` is being matched by Web API's route as you have removed `api` from its route template. if a request matches a route, further probing is not done on rest of the routes.
You probably have the default order in Global.asax where Web API routes are registered first and then the MVC routes. Could you share how your Global.asax looks like?

EDIT:
Based on your last comment, if you install HelpPage nuget package, make sure that the order in your Global.asax looks like this:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Comment: I have not installed it as an area, just followed the tutorial I linked to which doesn't mention areas anywhere.

Comment: Hmm...didn't you install HelpPage from the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`?...I ask because when you do this helppage gets installed in its own `HelpPage` area...have you already taken a look at this package?...

Comment: If you add to your answer your suggestion to use the Nuget package I'll mark it as accepted. Not quite working but the problem is different to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error today.

```
<Error>
  <Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'xxx'.</Message>
  <MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'xxx'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

In my case after 2 days of debuging I finally solved it by setting the microsoft report viewer dll to "Copy to local". Makes no sense to me how it could be related, but maby this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error:

```
Error><Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53569/api/values'.</Message><MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'values'.</MessageDetail></Error>
```

By default when I created new controller in asp.net web forms application, it was like this:

```
ValuesController1 : ApiController
```

I just simply removed "1", and make it:

```
ValuesController : ApiController
```

And it works, don't know if it is a bug or whatever, but it made big trouble for me.

Comment: a controller written xyz in the url, matches controller class named xyzController thats why the '1' was making trouble